# Can I run the Spark jobs in the Iguazio platform with the Spot instances?

Tags: apache-spark, nuclio

I have some big Spark workloads that can be run with a flexible schedule. I would like to take advantage of the low cost of the Spot instances of the cloud providers. Can I run the Spark jobs in the Iguazio platform with the Spot instances?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run Spark jobs in Iguazio using spot instances. To run the job on the Spot instance, first, you will need to config a new NodeGroup with Spot instances (e.g. added-spot-ng). Then in your job, specify the node selection like the code snippet below:

```
fn.with_node_selection(node_selector={'app.iguazio.com/node-group': 'added-spot-ng'})
```

This way, the function (Spark job) will be scheduled to the Spot instance node-group.